# how to feed data in TensorFlow RNN?

Tags: python, batch-file, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

Here is my data format: 100x20, 20 feature and 100 rows, and this is the tensorflow RNN input data format:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, step_size, input_size], name='input_placeholder')
```

I know input_size=20, I want Truncated Backpropagation is n step, and feed one rows once. So how to set batch_size and step_size? Is that step_size=n?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific of what have you tried, what's the problem and what is your goal. None of these seem clear to me.

Comment: my data format is 100x20, is 2D, but tensorflow input format is 3D, I don't know the mean of those three parameter[atch_size, step_size, input_size], what should I reshape my data, thanks.

Comment: I think you should read a tutorial over tensorflow which would guide you more normally to what you ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not clear what your data is.
Do you mean,it is 100 rows,each row for a sample with 20 features?

Or each sample have 20 features for 100 times, the dataset contains N samples : N * 100 *20?

For the 1st case, you should reshape 20 features as step_size*input_size.for example:

```
X.reshape(-1,4,5)
```

For the 2nd case

```
X.reshape(-1,100,20)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is 1st case, I wonder why reshape 20 features.

Comment: see [Understanding LSTM Networks](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/)  and [Recurrent Neural Networks](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent). I think features here you get may not concerned with time seqs, but if you want to use RNN models, you should reshape them with steps * features_at_this_step. Because the RNN cell takes x0,x1...xt (See link 1).